# At what position do we insert the new coefficient in the weights for extended Dynkin Diagrams?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, dynkin-diagrams

Given a set of weights of a representation and the corresponding extended Dynkin diagram for some Lie algebra, we can delete a node, which yields the maximal subalgebra. I know how to draw the extended Dynkin and that we add minus the highest root as a new node. Then we can compute the coefficient for every weight corresponding to this new root.

My problem is: Where do I insert this new coefficient? At the end? At the position of the new node in the Dynkin diagram? At the position of the node that I delete from the Dynkin diagram?

As an example let's consider $E_8$ and say we delete the third node, which means
$E_8 \rightarrow SU(2) \otimes SU(3)\otimes A_5$. Where do I put the new coefficient in order to get the weights for the maximal subalgebra? Between 7 and 8, which is the position of the new node? Or at position 3, which would mean that I replace the deleted node/coefficient with the new node/coefficient?

I'm using the numbering and weight convention of LieArt. For the extended Dynkin diagram, see page 37 [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.6379)

EDIT: It seems as this question is too trivial. Nevertheless a short one sentence comment would help me so much!

Comment: What is «LieArt»? Please when you provide a link to a published document mention the title and the author; when linking to arxiv, do not link to the actual PDF file but to the abstract page of the paper.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez LieArt is a Mathematica package for Lie algebra computations. I changed the link

Answer (score 1):

The coefficent is inserted at the position of the deleted simple root.

An explicit example can be found at page 73 [here.](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~ilarion/FILES/RepLectures.pdf)

In addition at page 147 [here](http://phyweb.lbl.gov/~rncahn/www/liealgebras/texall.pdf) Cahn writes, "... and use it in place of one of the old coefficents".